# Explanation for len(set())

Tags: python

Quick question, I was coding a small program in Python and was looking for a way to make a condition to only allow the input of 4 numbers if that input has the same len that I want and to make sure that all the numbers in it are unique.
After searching for a bit on the web I found several people giving the same solution, it was `len(set(input)) == size` (size of my number) in my case.

It works well, but I fail to understand how it really works and I want to know.
I've also tried removing the `len` from that and it worked anyway so I have little clue what are the effects of each thing in this small piece of code.

So even though it allows me to create a condition that makes sure each of the 4 numbers are unique I would love it if someone could explain to me how it works.

Thanks in advance.

PS: If anyone wonders what it is I'm practicing by making my own version of Cows & Bulls. So given a random number using random.sample the user then has to try to guess what the number is. The conditions I mentioned were used upon the user's input.

Comment: A set can only contain unique elements. So `len(set(x))` tells you the size of the set of unique elements of `x`.

Comment: What do you mean by "it worked anyway"? `set(input) == size` won't tell you if the number of unique items in `input` is equal to `size`.

Comment: Do you really remove `len`, or did you mean to say that you removed `set`?

Comment: You're right Barmar, it was probably a coincidence that happened when I tested it. And since I didn't really understand why, I mistook it as working, but it was in fact wrong :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A [**`set`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) is a datastructure for:

> constructing and manipulating unordered collections of **unique** elements.

These collections have to be *hashable* as well. But we are lucky: strings and characters are hashable.

The point is that if we construct a set form `set(['1','4','1','5','2'])`, it will thus construct a collection of *unique* elements. So adding `'1'` twice here, does not makes any difference, the result is `set(['1', '4', '5', '2'])`  (or more conveniently written `{'1', '4', '5', '2'}`). With `len(..)` we obtain the *size* of a collection. So the size of that set is the number of *unique* characters of the input.

So if we write `len(set(some_string))` we will first turn a string into a set. This is possible since a string is an *iterable* of the characters. So Python sees a string as an ordered collection of characters. `'abc'`, is a collection of `'a'`, `'b'`, and `'c'`. So every digit is seen as an element and added to the set.

But adding the same digit a second time, has no effect. So that means that we end up with a set where every digit is added once. By then calculating the `len(..)` we obtain the number of *unique* digits. We can then compare that number with a given number.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, every input is a string, which can be converted to a list of characters. When a list is converted to a set, it keeps the unique elements.

So, when your code turns the string of digits into a set, it only keeps the unique digits. Then, when you find the length, it returns the number of unique digits.